# Insert value to DB using MYSQL query in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert data to my database. I have a for loop. I would like to get all the value one by one and insert them to database. I am trying out the following:

//Name VALUE is there in $name(1,2,3)

```
$name1 = addslashes($_POST['name1']);
$name2 = addslashes($_POST['name2']);
$name3 = addslashes($_POST['name3']);
```

//address VALUE is there in $address(1,2,3)

```
$address1 = addslashes($_POST['address1']);
$address2 = addslashes($_POST['address2']);
$address3 = addslashes($_POST['address3']);

echo $name1;
echo $address1;


for ($x=1; $x<=3; $x++) 
{
  $sql="INSERT INTO house (name, address)VALUES(''name'+$x',''address'+$x')";
  $result=mysql_query($sql);
} 

if($result)
{

  echo "<strong> <font size='18'>Thank you for updating your address</font></strong>";
  echo "<BR>";
  echo "<strong> <font size='18'><a href='logout.php'>Sign out</a></font></strong>";
}
else
{
  echo "<strong> <font size='18'>There was an error, please try again!</font></strong>";
  echo "<BR>";
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$sql' (T_VARIABLE
```

I am 100% sure I am doing something wrong the value part in my query I am not sure what would be the format to insert value using for loop.

Can somebody help me fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you don't need to predefine those `name` and `address` variables before the query. Your `for` loop could be simplified like this:

```
for($x=1;$x<3;$x++){
  $name = addslashes($_POST["name".$x]);
  $address = addslashes($_POST["address".$x]);
  $sql="INSERT INTO house (name, address)VALUES('$name','$address')";
  $result=mysql_query($sql);
  // now deal with the result here
}
```

Comment: I used your logic. It is working fine now! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$sql="INSERT INTO house (name, address)VALUES('name+{$x}','address+{$x}')";
```

instead of this

```
 $sql="INSERT INTO house (name, address)VALUES(''name'+$x',''address'+$x')";
```

Comment: I don't think the + is intentional the OP may be mixing JavaScript and php.

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix I am considering "name+{$x}" as value

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
"INSERT INTO house (name, address)VALUES('name{$x}','address{$x}')";
```

or

```
"INSERT INTO house (name, address)VALUES('name".$x."','address".$x."')";
```

p.s. is the + intentional or are you mixing a bit of JavaScript by accident into your php & Sql.

Also Look into PDO, you can prepare the query outside the loop and then inject the values and it will do all the sanitation and quoting of the variables for you.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO house (name, address)VALUES(:name,:address)";

$stmt = $Pdo->prepare($sql);
for ($x=1; $x<=3; $x++) {
   $stmt->execute( array(':name' => 'name'.$x, ':address'=>'address'.$x ));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your having a problem with quote and it seems you are trying to achieve a lambda variable. Try this.

```
$name = "name";
$address = "address";
$sql="INSERT INTO house (name, address)VALUES(".$$name.$x.", ".$$address.$x.")";
```

Comment: I avoid the $$ like the plague fist time i saw that in some code I thought it was a typo, took hours of googling to figure it out.. lol

Comment: hahaha! @ArtisiticPhoenix Amazing right? It's popular in the most known commercial Frameworks.

Comment: its a variable variable, lets you get a variable by using a string name for it so the variable $$address.$x could be thought like this $($address.$x) where the stuff in the brackets are processed first makeing it like $address1, $address2, it would be better to use the $x in the post array key like this $_POST['address'.$x] with an isset() or something.

Comment: @NoobEditor Try using that, it will helps a lot in your future projects. Always think out of the box :)

Comment: @Imat yea it was after i only had a year of experience with programing and was tasked to refactor a site written for php 4 . something to 5 . something, but it was tough but a good learning experience for me

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix are you familiar with the magic method _get? I think  that was the code that they use there. Try this in one of your class. public function __get($property)
 {
  if(property_exists($this, $property)) return $this->{$property};
 
  else return NULL;
 }

Comment: @ Imat - I use magic methods a lot (more then i should), but they are well documented unlike the $$ and try googling for that what do you put in? double dollar php, as a side magic methods are great for making a data container class, then i discovered ArrayAccess and SPL and dont let me forget Reflection -- I dont think your code should work because __get is not called when the property exists.